# Can't login with FacebookWebBot

Tags: facebook, python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying FacebookWebBot from the official Python website, using Python 3.4 with Selenium and PhantomJS installed as the readme says. It just returns the message `"Fail to login"`, checked the username and password are correct. Any ideas what could it be ?

```
from FacebookWebBot import *
bot=FacebookBot()
bot.set_page_load_timeout(10)
bot.login("email","password")
```

Other file summarized

```
# coding: utf-8
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time
import os
import json

selfProfile = "https://mbasic.facebook.com/profile.php?fref=pb"


def mfacebookToBasic(url):
    """Reformat a url to load mbasic facebook instead of regular facebook, return the same string if
    the url don't contains facebook"""

    if "m.facebook.com" in url:
        return url.replace("m.facebook.com", "mbasic.facebook.com")
    elif "www.facebook.com" in url:
        return url.replace("www.facebook.com", "mbasic.facebook.com")
    else:
        return url


class Person():
    """Basic class for people's profiles"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.profileLink = ""
        self.addLink = ""

    def __str__(self):
        s = ""
        s += self.name + ":\n"
        s += "Profile Link: " + self.profileLink
        if self.addLink != "":
            s += "Addlink ->: " + self.addLink
        return s

    def __repr__(self):
        self.__str__()


class Post():
    """Class to contain information about a post"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.posterName = ""
        self.text = ""
        self.numLikes = 0
        self.time = ""
        self.privacy = ""
        self.posterLink = ""
        self.linkToComment = ""
        self.linkToLike = ""
        self.linkToLikers = ""
        self.linkToReport = ""
        self.groupLink = ""
        self.linkToShare = ""
        self.linkToMore = ""
        self.numComents = 0

    def toDict(self):
        return self.__dict__.copy()

    def fromDict(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d.copy()

    def from_json(self, j):
        self.fromDict(json.loads(j))

    def from_json_file(self, f):
        self.fromDict(json.loads(open(f, "rt").read()))

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self.toDict())

    def __str__(self):
        s = "\nPost by " + self.posterName + ": "
        s += self.text + "\n"
        s += "Likes: " + str(self.numLikes) + " - "
        s += "Comments: " + str(self.numComents) + " - "
        s += self.time + " "
        s += " - Privacy: " + self.privacy + "\n-"
        s += "\n Comment -> " + self.linkToComment + "\n"
        return s

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
)


class FacebookBot(webdriver.PhantomJS):
    """Main class for browsing facebook"""

    def __init__(self):
        # pathToPhantomJs ="
        """relativePhatomJs = "\\phantomjs.exe"
        service_args = None
        if images == False:
            service_args = ['--load-images=no', ]
        if pathToPhantomJs == None:
            path = self, os.getcwd() + relativePhatomJs
        else:
            path = pathToPhantomJs
            webdriver.PhantomJS.__init__(self, path, service_args=service_args)
        """
        webdriver.PhantomJS.__init__(self, desired_capabilities=dcap)

    def get(self, url):
        """The make the driver go to the url but reformat the url if is for facebook page"""
        super().get(mfacebookToBasic(url))

    def login(self, email, password):
        """Log to facebook using email (str) and password (str)"""

        url = "https://mbasic.facebook.com"
        self.get(url)

        email_element = self.find_element_by_name("email")

        email_element.send_keys(email)
        pass_element = self.find_element_by_name("pass")
        pass_element.send_keys(password)
        pass_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        try:
            self.find_element_by_name("xc_message")
            print("Logged in")
            return True
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print("Fail to login")
            return False
```

Comment: Please post the code for login and related. It's really hard to work on a belief of something being correct until really seen.

Comment: And how does phantomjs or selenium come into play here?

Comment: @AakashVerma you want to read the other file, I didnt make time to add it to the post before you read it, apparently.

Comment: Yeah, maybe..no, just the login code. Which one are you running?

Comment: Use of any such automation to access their site is against Facebook ToS. If you want to interact with people or content on Facebook - use their API.